# Drawing pie charts with vectors with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, vector, maps

Has any one got any examples of drawing pie charts with vectors as markers with OpenLayers?

Comment: Please check out http://thematicmapping.org/playground/openlayers_piecharts_geojson_google_chart.php

Comment: I'm sure there'll be a growing number of people asking this question with Google Image charts being deprecated...I'm  searching high and low for a solution myself. The options I've looked at so far are pretty terrible. #1 draw charts directly somehow by hand in OL (out of poly's?); #2 use Google Charts print function to export an image from the `<canvas>` tag, which is hacky as hell and doesn't even support *IE9*.

Comment: I would go for ExtJS (N.B. i am not evangelist of that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, took me a couple of hours but I found *one* way to do it.

It requires you to use [dojo.js](http://dojotoolkit.org/), (which unfortunately I can't use for my project but thought I'd share for anybody else that's looking).

Basically, as I understand it, dojo adds a custom wrapper to openlayers map which allows you to add Dojo GFX Shapes and Widgets - which includes Pie Charts!

See a good demo here: http://acuriousanimal.com/2012/01/23/dojo-openlayers-new-challenges

Answer (score 4):

An example can be found at this website:

http://thematicmapping.org/playground/openlayers_piecharts_geojson_google_chart.php